# OnTriggerEnter2D doesn't work after switching scenes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have a game that is similar to "Flappy Bird" and I have main menu where I can start game and change skin of a pigeon. My skin collection is implemented with scroll rect and in the center there is a trigger which starts an animation of scaling a pigeon, it works fine until I click "start" and the scene changes to game and when I return to my main menu and click "skins" this trigger doesn't work anymore.

[image: Main menu]

[image: Skins collection before changing scenes]

[image: Skins collection after changing scenes]

Script what is attached to all scroll rect elements to detect collisions with trigger:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ResizeFieldScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger is working");
        if(collider.tag == "ResizeField")
        {
            Debug.Log("Condition is working");
            _anim.SetBool("isInTrigger", true);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        _anim.SetBool("isInTrigger", false);
    }
}
```

Script what is attached to an empty object to change scenes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<string> sceneNameList;
    private string sceneToFind;
    private int index = 0;

    public void SceneChanger()
    {
        sceneToFind = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;

        foreach(string str in sceneNameList)
        {
            if(str == sceneToFind)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(index);
                index = 0;
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void BackMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your trigger did not fire the animation. It's possible that the animation won't be triggered inside the "if statement". You could try the following code: collider.gameObject.tag=="ResizeField".

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT, I have 2 Debug.Logs in my OnTriggerEnter, one is before if statement and one is inside it. Neither first nor second doesn't work, that's why the problem is not in collider.gameObject.tag. P.S. I've tried it really doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

OnTriggerEnter2D doesn't work after switching scenes. We could use OnTriggerEnter2D to jump scenes.

code show as below:

```
 private void Update() {
 // If E is pressed
 if (Input. GetKeyDown(KeyCode. E)) {
    // scene switching
    SceneManager.LoadScene(4);  
    }
 }

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider collision) {

 if (collision. tag == "ResizeField") {
     // The UI prompts the user to press E to jump
     EnterDialog.SetActive(true);
     Debug.Log("Condition is working");
     // _anim.SetBool("isInTrigger", true);
 }
}
```

Hope it helps you.